# How do I install Chrome browser on the libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9) operating system?

Tags: kodi, libreelec

I installed libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9) operating systems on Raspberry Pi3 B+.

How do I install Chrome browser on the libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9) operating system?
I tried a lot but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Can you please detail a bit more of what you did and what errors you encountered - Chrome as such does not actually run on ARM so where you trying Chromium or Vivaldi or Edge etc (many 'flavours' are based on the same root software)??? What makes you think this will actually run as they do not offer it in the 'add-ons' (it is available on x86) Have you tried any other add-ons?

Comment: HI, I want to open a page of a site and play a video.What plugins do you think I should use?

Comment: I've edited the question tags - this is nothing to do with running Kodi, a browser on Pi OS or use of the GUI Desktop

Comment: HI. Can I use the browser Chromium ?
How can I add to libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9)?

Answer (score 2):

In this case (web browsing) I would start by looking at the add-ons for Kodi [here](https://kodi.wiki/view/Category:Web_interface_add-ons).

To explain to others with a similar questions:

LibreELEC is a minimum operating system designed to run Kodi (and very little else).  They describe it as a ['Just enough OS'](https://libreelec.wiki) to run / develop on.

[Kodi](https://kodi.wiki/view/Main_Page) has two main ways of adding to its abilities:

1. By the use off [add-ons](https://kodi.wiki/view/Add-ons). Think apps as per mobile devices
2. By the use of [Docker](https://libreelec.wiki/installation/docker) containers.  Think part OS, part application

Things to note:

- Not all add-ons or containers are available for all platforms.
- Arm development is 'classed' (maybe too strong a word) by Kodi as early/on-going.  This is made more complex by the lack of standards in hardware codec decoding across ARM platforms and the multiple ways of running Kodi on SBCs (
- Browsing on a Pi (esp media) can be very painful even on the latest versions of the Pi (Dec 2020) - media extensions for browsers may be required to optimise hardware and they may not be ARM compatible
- Some browsers recommend system changes (e.g. Vivaldi says to [increase swap space](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/install-update/raspberry-pi/)) that may not be obvious / applied during install and may not be possible on reduced operating systems.
- Some browser builds (e.g. [Ventz](https://blog.vpetkov.net) implementation using WideVine) may not be installable / work on the cut down OS as they are 'normally' (again possibly a too strong a word) designed / tested to run on full OS versions.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no solution.

Comment: HI. Can I use the browser Chromium ?
How can I add to libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9)?

Comment: Appologies - if its not in any of the add-ons or docker containers you will have to either create the add-on or docker container.  Out of the two I would go for the docker container as that may well pull in the OS requirements.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your follow up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Chrome is closed source software, meaning you need to get it pre-compiled, and it is not available for the Pi's hardware.

You can use Chromium, the open source version.

Comment: HI. Can I use the browser Chromium ?
How can I add to libreelec 9.2.6 (kodi 18.9)?

Comment: I'm actually not a libreelec user, but based on the other answer it sounds like you can't -- you'll have to use a different OS.